# How to get full html of web page via php

Tags: php, curl

I want to get all data or only content of any web page via php code if any one have knowledge about that please help me how to get this gole

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Seriously, show a little effort. Did you even try googling? StackOverflow isn't a place where you can ask people to code everything for you, but to ask for help when you're stuck after actually trying something yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that possible with the following code?

```
file_get_contents("http://www.domain.tld/page.html");
```

Comment: No, a lot of pages won't accept that call. You'll have to use e.g. curl.

Comment: Why wouldn't 'alot of pages' not accept this? I rarely encountered problems with this approach. It is not that I don't believe you, but I'm genuinely curious as to why this wouldn't work in most cases?

Answer (score 1):

Call this function along with your `URL` to get your html response.

```
    <?php
        function curl($url){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }
        ?>
echo curl('http://www.google.com'); //your url..
```

When running this code, PHP will give you the entire page...If you intend to scrap the page read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Do read about various `cURL` parameters set in the code and various other.